# How to use LSTM in pytorch?

Tags: python, nlp, pytorch, lstm

I have been trying to add LSTM to my pytorch model, but the issue I have is that it asks for 3d input, I cannot understand what am I doing wrong. I have done something like this:

```
import torch.nn as nn
torch.manual_seed(random_state)

from torch.nn.utils.rnn import pack_padded_sequence, pad_packed_sequence

class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, vocab_size= len(vocab), embed_dim= 32, num_class= 3):
        super().__init__()

        self.embedding = nn.EmbeddingBag(vocab_size, embed_dim, sparse=True)

        self.lstm = nn.LSTM(input_size= embed_dim, hidden_size= embed_dim, num_layers=5)

        self.lin = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(in_features= embed_dim, out_features= embed_dim),
            nn.Linear(in_features= embed_dim, out_features= embed_dim),
            nn.Linear(in_features= embed_dim, out_features= 16),
            nn.Linear(in_features= 16, out_features= 16),
            nn.Linear(in_features= 16, out_features= 8),
            nn.Linear(in_features= 8, out_features= 8),
        )

        self.out = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(in_features= 8, out_features= num_class),
            # nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
        )

        self.init_weights()

    def init_weights(self):
        initrange = 0.5
        self.embedding.weight.data.uniform_(-initrange, initrange)
        for i in self.lin:
          if isinstance(i, nn.LSTM): continue
          i.weight.data.uniform_(-initrange, initrange)
          i.bias.data.zero_()

    def forward(self, text, offsets):
        x = self.embedding(text, offsets)

        ########## In the next two lines I have no idea what I'm doing. 
        x = x.view(1, x.shape[0], -1)
        x = self.lstm(x)[0][0]
        ########## If you remove these two lines, the model works half-decent

        x = self.lin(x)
        return self.out(x)

model = Net()
model.to(device)
```

So, the place that confuses me is the one where I have left the comment. The reason is that I have a batch size of 10, the text itself, and offsets, which are needed for the embeddings.

`text` is a vector `torch.Size([360])` (not always 360 since the length of the sentence may be different), and offsets are always `torch.Size([10])`. The output of the `self.embedding` then has a constant size of `torch.Size([10, 32])`. Where is the third dimension supposed to be taken from? I have looked at the examples from other people and it seems that what they do is something similar to what I do next, but while this works, the model becomes absolutely awful and only predicts one class, so I think something is wrong here. Does anyone know the proper way of doing this?

If you want to see the full code in action (including the datasets), this is almost a complete copy of [this](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/text_sentiment_ngrams_tutorial.html) tutorial on the PyTorch website.